# Template.loginButtons is undefined when using a different package (blaze.render & react)

Tags: meteor, reactjs, meteor-blaze

```
this.view = Blaze.render(Template.loginButtons, ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.container));
```

Using the accounts-ui package this works fine but when switching it out for another UI package (ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3) I suddenly get a

```
'Can't render undefined'
```

in my browser, shouldn't they both work since the template names are the same? I can insert them both using {{> loginButtons}} in a plain html file but not using the blaze.render method when switching to reactjs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That package is intended as a complete replacement for accounts-ui, so there is no guarantee `Template.loginButtons` will be defined.  Looking at the package's code, though, it appears `Template._loginButtons` is a valid object. Hope that helps!

Comment: That was it! I thought the text in {{> }} would be the template name. Thank you :)